# Error when loading hortonworks docker image

Tags: hadoop, docker, hortonworks-data-platform

I am getting next error when loading image into docker:

```
[root@xxx docker]# docker load < HDP_2.6_docker_05_05_2017_15_01_40.tar.gz
b1b065555b8a: Loading layer [==================================================>] 202.2 MB/202.2 MB
bcedae1b8073: Loading layer [=================================>                 ] 8.437 GB/12.68 GB
```

*ApplyLayer exit status 1 stdout:  stderr: write /usr/lib/ams-hbase/lib/hadoop-common-2.7.3.2.6.0.3-8.jar: no space left on device*

Also I did check if there is enough space on this machine:

```
[root@Jerusalem docker]# df -a 
Filesystem              1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
rootfs                          -        -         -    - /
sysfs                           0        0         0    - /sys
proc                            0        0         0    - /proc
devtmpfs                 12122784        0  12122784   0% /dev
securityfs                      0        0         0    - /sys/kernel/security
tmpfs                    12138348        0  12138348   0% /dev/shm
devpts                          0        0         0    - /dev/pts
tmpfs                    12138348     9200  12129148   1% /run
tmpfs                    12138348        0  12138348   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
cgroup                          0        0         0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd
pstore                          0        0         0    - /sys/fs/pstore
cgroup                          0        0         0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event
cgroup                          0        0         0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer
cgroup                          0        0         0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio
cgroup                          0        0         0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset
cgroup                          0        0         0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/pids
cgroup                          0        0         0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/memory
cgroup                          0        0         0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct
cgroup                          0        0         0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio
cgroup                          0        0         0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/devices
cgroup                          0        0         0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb
configfs                        0        0         0    - /sys/kernel/config
/dev/mapper/centos-root  52403200 31274244  21128956  60% /
selinuxfs                       0        0         0    - /sys/fs/selinux
systemd-1                       -        -         -    - /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc
debugfs                         0        0         0    - /sys/kernel/debug
mqueue                          0        0         0    - /dev/mqueue
hugetlbfs                       0        0         0    - /dev/hugepages
nfsd                            0        0         0    - /proc/fs/nfsd
/dev/sda1                  508588   352188    156400  70% /boot
/dev/mapper/centos-home 910513788 17008076 893505712   2% /home
sunrpc                          0        0         0    - /var/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs
tmpfs                     2427672        0   2427672   0% /run/user/0
/dev/mapper/centos-root  52403200 31274244  21128956  60% /var/lib/docker/overlay
binfmt_misc                     0        0         0    - /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc
```

[root@xxx docker]# docker version
Client:
 Version:      17.03.1-ce
 API version:  1.27
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   c6d412e
 Built:        Mon Mar 27 17:05:44 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.03.1-ce
 API version:  1.27 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   c6d412e
 Built:        Mon Mar 27 17:05:44 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false
[root@xxx docker]#

Any help will be appreciated,
Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manage to resolve this issue by resizing root partition, added extra 80G to /dev/mapper/centos-root. There was just about 10G free, so it was causing an issue to add 12G image. There is a number of articles online how to resize/add extra space to CentOs partitions.